# How to use "ctrl c" to kill all process?

Tags: linux, bash, linux-kernel, exe, sigint

I have an exe file compiled from C++ code. And I use bash to set up Linux environment and to call this `.exe` programme.

Now coming to the problem, most of the time, users would like to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> to kill the processes when they finish using the programme or when they don't want to continue.

The bash process is terminated by <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> properly, however, the `.exe` is usually running without being killed. So users need to use `kill -9 xxx` to kill the process. If they forget to kill, their CPU could be fully occupied.

How shall I proceed to solve this problem ? Shall I do something for the code of exe file or for the bash script?

Thanks

Comment: `As loog as they forget to kill, their CPU could be fully occupied` sounds like something is wrong with your code

Comment: The exe is really heavy loaded. In top, I can see the CPU is 30% taken. But for the specific process, it shows 100% CPU. I guess since it is running on the sever, the whole CPUs are not occpupied.

Comment: `Shall I do something for the code of exe file or ...` -- Yes, do something about the code.  Fix it.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

./yourbinary &
pid=$!

trap "kill -9 $pid" SIGINT

wait
```

Answer (score 0):

This is from my old code written sometime long back. I had used this to kill ffmpeg, I am also pasting the code. I am not using ctr+c, I am using process pid to kill it. i think this must be the good way.

```
        else if (strcmp(client_message,"2-off") == 0) {
            printf("start audio streeaming will be turned of\n");
            fp = popen("pidof ffmpeg", "r");
            fgets(line, 100, fp);
            pid = atoi(line);
            printf("pid = %d\n",pid);
            sprintf(command,"kill %d",pid);
            status = system(command);
            pclose(fp);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you detach your program in bash script? Do you call it like this:

```
exe&
```

You can delete "&" and script will wait for program end before executing next command.

If the problem is not there, try to attach your program to console. Example, in Qt project string:

```
CONFIG += console
```

in .pro file attaches application to console and script will wait for application end and terminate application with Ctrl+C.